# Intermittent data corruption, how to diagnose?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, data-corruption, memory-test

**TL;DR:** I thought I had a data-at-rest corruption error on 2 SSDs, but I think it is after reading the data. How can I diagnose where the failing part is?

My ML training algorithm opens thousands of files (readonly), and yesterday one of the files showed up corrupted. However, when I started exploring the differences between the 3 copies (1 on each of 2 SSDs and 1 HDD), things got more strange. All of the dates and sizes matched perfectly, but the md5sums showed differences in 10 files.

What is even stranger, after I made sure all 3 copies were in sync (using rsync with checksum), a different file on 1 SSD randomly showed corruption. So I compared the md5sum, and it was the odd one out of the 3 copies. However, when I tested it again 2 minutes later, the md5sum matched the other 2. This shows that it isn't corruption on the disk (data-at-rest).

How do I go about figuring out what is failing? I'm going to run a long memtest (which previously passed, a year ago), but I'm unsure what else I can do.

**Specs**

- Dell T7500 (A18 BIOS - latest from Dell)
- 2x Xeon X5675
- 64GB (4x16GB ECC)
- Drives:

  - Samsung 850 EVO 250GB (SSD FW:EMT03B6Q)
  - Samsung 860 EVO 500GB (SSD FW:RVT01B6Q)
  - WD Blue 4TB (HDD FW: 80.00A80)
- All 3 drives are connect to:

  - IO Crest 4-port SATA III PCIe 2.0 x2 Controller Card Green, SI-PEX40057 (chipset Marvell 88SE9230)
  - Used because motherboard is SATA 2.0, and I needed the higher throughput. This was the only SATA card that I could boot from, given the Dell's BIOS limitations.

**output of `free -h`**
(cache is full because I just ran new match of md5sums on all 3 drives)

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            62G        1.2G        312M         11M         61G         61G
Swap:          2.0G          0B        2.0G
```

**output of `sudo lshw -C memory`**
(I can confirm the 4 sticks are sitting in the correct slots according to the manual. MB DIMM 1 and 2, Riser DIMM 1 and 2)

```
*-firmware
    description: BIOS
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    physical id: 0
    version: A18
    date: 10/15/2018
    size: 64KiB
    capacity: 1984KiB
    capabilities: pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing escd cdboot bootselect edd int13floppytoshiba int13floppy720 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot
*-cache:0
    description: L1 cache
    physical id: 700
    size: 384KiB
    capacity: 384KiB
    capabilities: internal write-back unified
    configuration: level=1
*-cache:1
    description: L2 cache
    physical id: 701
    size: 1536KiB
    capacity: 1536KiB
    capabilities: internal varies unified
    configuration: level=2
*-cache:2
    description: L3 cache
    physical id: 704
    size: 12MiB
    capacity: 12MiB
    capabilities: internal varies unified
    configuration: level=3
*-cache:0
    description: L1 cache
    physical id: 702
    size: 384KiB
    capacity: 384KiB
    capabilities: internal write-back unified
    configuration: level=1
*-cache:1
    description: L2 cache
    physical id: 703
    size: 1536KiB
    capacity: 1536KiB
    capabilities: internal varies unified
    configuration: level=2
*-cache:2
    description: L3 cache
    physical id: 705
    size: 12MiB
    capacity: 12MiB
    capabilities: internal varies unified
    configuration: level=3
*-memory
    description: System Memory
    physical id: 1000
    slot: System board or motherboard
    size: 64GiB
    capabilities: ecc
    configuration: errordetection=multi-bit-ecc
    *-bank:0
       description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
       product: 9965516-433.A00LF
       vendor: AMD
       physical id: 0
       serial: CF38EF94
       slot: DIMM 1
       size: 16GiB
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:1
       description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
       product: 9965434-110.A00LF
       vendor: AMD
       physical id: 1
       serial: 2D25C605
       slot: DIMM 2
       size: 16GiB
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:2
       description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
       vendor: FFFFFFFFFFFF
       physical id: 2
       serial: FFFFFFFF
       slot: DIMM 3
       width: 64 bits
    *-bank:3
       description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
       vendor: FFFFFFFFFFFF
       physical id: 3
       serial: FFFFFFFF
       slot: DIMM 4
       width: 64 bits
    *-bank:4
       description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
       vendor: FFFFFFFFFFFF
       physical id: 4
       serial: FFFFFFFF
       slot: DIMM 5
       width: 64 bits
    *-bank:5
       description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
       vendor: FFFFFFFFFFFF
       physical id: 5
       serial: FFFFFFFF
       slot: DIMM 6
       width: 64 bits
    *-bank:6
       description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
       product: 9965434-110.A00LF
       vendor: AMD
       physical id: 6
       serial: 2E25EB05
       slot: RISER DIMM 1
       size: 16GiB
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:7
       description: DIMM DDR3 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
       product: 9965434-110.A00LF
       vendor: AMD
       physical id: 7
       serial: 2F25DC05
       slot: RISER DIMM 2
       size: 16GiB
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
    *-bank:8
       description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
       vendor: FFFFFFFFFFFF
       physical id: 8
       serial: FFFFFFFF
       slot: RISER DIMM 3
       width: 64 bits
    *-bank:9
       description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
       vendor: FFFFFFFFFFFF
       physical id: 9
       serial: FFFFFFFF
       slot: RISER DIMM 4
       width: 64 bits
    *-bank:10
       description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
       vendor: FFFFFFFFFFFF
       physical id: a
       serial: FFFFFFFF
       slot: RISER DIMM 5
       width: 64 bits
    *-bank:11
       description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous [empty]
       vendor: FFFFFFFFFFFF
       physical id: b
       serial: FFFFFFFF
       slot: RISER DIMM 6
       width: 64 bits
```

**Update 1**

Dell's built-in system diagnostics ran without issue (I stopped it from doing the memory tests, and did them with memtest86 instead).

Finished tests 1-8 of memtest86 v4 without issues.

I wrote a python script to get a dictionary of all the md5sums in a directory and ran it against the 3 copies simultaneously (but only 1 thread per drive*). It found 7 new discrepancies (out of 3000 files). These were about evenly divided among the 3 drives (so it isn't just an issue with the SSDs). And when I went back to check each of the 7 odd ones out, each md5sum now matched the other 2.

Current ideas:

- I thought that possibly having 2/3 workers accessing files per drive simultaneously might've been the issue, but I've now done a few tests that the errors still show up with sequential access.
- The SATA card is bad in some way. I'll reconnect all 3 drives to the motherboard and run the same test again.

**Seems likely to be the SATA card** Have now run 3 passes on all 3 drives after connecting them directly to the MB, with 0 md5sum discrepancies. Looks like the SATA card is flaky, and destined for the trash.

Comment: To start the diagnosis, edit your question and show me `free -h`. What brand SSD? Have you checked for firmware updates for them? Lets check your BIOS with `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. Tell me the exact make/model # of your computer. We may end up running a memory diagnostic later.

Comment: Thanks. I'll add those as soon as I finish the current memtest86 pass.

Comment: @heynnema updates added.

Comment: BIOS looks good. For the Samsung SSDs, you'll need to download `Samsung Magician` from https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/. Do you have anything (CPU/RAM/etc) overclocked?

Comment: Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C memory`. Let's check that your RAM is in slots A0/B0 and A1/B1, and are fully interleaved.

Comment: @heynnema I had already downloaded `Samsung Magician`, but I'm working on a way to get Windows running on a spare HD so that I can use it.

Comment: You might also be able to create a bootable DOS USB stick and do it that way. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WqDUCfU-e-A BTW memory looks good too. Good job!

Comment: Please see my partial answer for special instructions for installing the PCIe SATA card.

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

- Successfully ran Dell's built-in system diagnostics
- Confirmed that the BIOS is current at version A18
- Successfully run memtest without errors, memory is correctly installed for memory interleaving
- Reconfigured the SATA drives to the motherboard, instead of PCIe SATA card, and testing
- Downloaded `Samsung Magician` and will check for SSD firmware updates(1)

(1) strongly suspect we'll find something here

---

From the `IO Crest 4-port SATA III PCIe 2.0 x2 Controller Card Green, SI-PEX40057` manual [here](https://www.sybausa.com/index.php?route=product/product/download&download_id=225), we see special Linux install instructions...

Linux distributions with kernel version 2.6.19 and above include inbox drivers for IDE/ATA device. In most distributions, the kernel does not load the drivers for the inbox IDE/ATA devices by default. The procedure for enabling support for IDE/ATA device in Linux is as follows:

```
Enabling support for IDE/ATA devices during a Clean Installation of Linux
 To enable support during a Clean Installation of Linux:
 1. Boot from the Linux Installation CD/DVD
 2. Select Installation and press Enter
 3. Type the following command into the Boot Options command line:
        ata_generic.all_generic_ide=1
 4. Press Enter to continue with the Linux OS installation

Enabling Support for IDE/ATA Device on an Existing Installation of Linux
 To enable support during a Existing Installation of Linux:
 1. Login as root.
 2. Right-click the Desktop and select Open in Terminal.
 3. Type the following commands:
        ls
        cd/boot/grub
         vim menu.lst
 4. Type the following command at the end of the kernel line for the title 
    paragraph that lists the version information for the Linux distribution.
        ata_generic.all_generic_ide=1
 5. Browse to File and select Save.
 6. Reboot the system for the changes to take effect.
```

**Update #1:**

A suspect defective PCIe SATA card has been removed from the system.

Comment: Thank you, heynnema, for a very thorough back and forth. After running enough tests to convince myself that the SATA card was failing (it had been working for a year), I went back and checked reviews on the device and found the same thing—people found that it started failing after several months. I've decided to just live with the performance hit, as I don't see any reasonably-priced SATA cards with good reviews on the market right now.